# How can I confirm that the format given in the Latex template is correct?

Tags: fonts, margins

I am a new PhD student. Now, I am preparing to submit a paper to a conference. But I haven't submitted a paper before. I want to know if I use the `Latex` template given by the conference party to write a paper, how can I confirm that the format is correct. For example, the requirements of the paper are:
[image]

This is the requirement of this conference. Its Latex template can be found here. https://www.microarch.org/micro54/

**Initially, I thought that this template should have all the relevant parameters set, but it is not.**
For example, Space between columns 0.25in. When I compared the pdf file generated by the template with the papers of previous years, I found that this parameter in the template was not set.

I didn’t find the font and margin settings in this template. What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: If the conference offers a template, I would not worry about it. Just use it. If a conference refuses a paper for the format, it is not worth sending anything (unless is a typography one, that is). Jokes apart: do not worry about adjusting the template until somebody from the conference (or whatever) asks you to do it --- and normally at that point you have your contribution already accepted.

Comment: Sometimes it may happen that a paper is desk-rejected because it uses a too small font to circumvent the page limit or something similar - but if you use the template as provided then that indeed should not happen. I have seen several times though that the Microsoft Word version of a template has different defaults than the LaTeX template for the same conference, which is a bit unprofessional but it also indicates that style variations from the authors will probably not be punished very strictly.

Comment: Also, it has happen to me that sometimes when submitting with EDAS it throws an error because one margin is too small. You can use the geometry package and compensate for it by shifting text up, down, left or right depending on the error. But this is only important if you receive the notice that something is wrong with the template. Usually, it does not happen, no point worrying over it until (if) you receive it

Comment: Thank you. But how can I check which font size is used?